# Asked in interview questions

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract only first 3 characters from entire column name Department in sql server

```
ID  Department  Salary  Designation
1   Dept 1  20000   M1
2   Dept 2  23000   M2
3   Dept 3  25000   M3
4   Dept 4  50000   M4
5   Dept 5  30000   M5
6   Dept 6  20070   M6
```

O/P should be

```
Departement
Dep
Dep
Dep
Dep
Dep
Dep
```

please help this was asked in interview?

Comment: `Left(department,3)` or `substring(department,1,3)`

Comment: Why exactly are you applying for SQL based jobs if you don't even know what the `left` function is or does...?

Comment: and to add the previous comment... if you don't even know how to figure out the answer with google or reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select left(Department,3) from t
```